# Azwar's interpretation of Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, ramanujacharya, azwar, manavala-mamunigal

I heard that as per the compositions of Azwars, The Ramavatara took place not to kill Ravana and Kumbhakarna, but to correct bhAgavata apacharam.

1) First of all, is that true? Is that mentioned in any of Azwar's pasurams? What apacharam was corrected, and who committed it?
2) If not explicitly mentioned in any of the Azwar's works, is that a belief held by the followers of Sri Ramanuja's school?
3) Has His Holiness Sri Ramanujacharya or Sri Vedandta Desika or Sri Manavala Mamunigal commented this way?

Any answers with details (references if possible) will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its given in adbuta ramayana I guess.

Comment: @Visheshreddy Thanks for the comment. I don't remember seeing it, but will go back and check. Do you recall the exact verse / chapter?